# ImportError: cannot import name 'nonwhitespace_re' from 'bs4.element'

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am new python learner. When I import beautifulsoup, it throws the following import error. My bs4 version is 4.8.2

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

> ImportError: cannot import name 'nonwhitespace_re' from 'bs4.element'

what should i do? 
[image: Traceback]

Comment: Please provide whole backtrace.

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing the issue. Try to install a previous version like
pip install beautifulsoup4==4.7 or try to uninstall and reinstall it. There might be an issue while installation

Comment: i uninstall and reinstall several times, it didn't work.

Comment: i add the backtrace

Comment: just try statements import bs4 and import BeautifulSoup, Tell if any of them is working